# Why it works in SPARK

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm a newbie to learn Spark, I created a fairly small piece of source code to evaluate the differences between driver and worker process in cluster. to my surprise, the code works which I don't really understand on why it works. (I setup standalone Spark cluster with 1 master node and 3 worker nodes, and those four machines also have HDFS underlying).

Here is some of the source code:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

columns = ['aaa','bbb']

def test_map(row): 
    for column in columns: 
        row["ID"] = row["ID"] + "_" + column
return row

newDF = data3.rdd.map(test_map).toDF()
newDF.write.format("csv").save("hdfs://VAZL00/data/output/")
```

The above code work correctly, for each row, it will append "_aaa_bbb" to the ID column.  However, I really don't understand why it works, here the columns variable is actually defined in Driver, and the test_map function is the RDD function that is actually executed in several worker processes of Spark Cluster, since the code works, I assume the value of columns variable will be passed to all the worker processes before the execution of test_map function? I searched from google but don't get answer on the variable scope in Spark application. Does anyone know why the test_map function would get the value of columns variable during spark runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is pyspark picking up a variable that was not broadcast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337446/why-is-pyspark-picking-up-a-variable-that-was-not-broadcast)

Comment: You are right, I get answer there, thanks a lot.